# What is the proper syntax for returning the first and last results of a query on a report?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The database links 2 tables with a  primary key `[OrderID]` in the parent table which links to `[OrderIDFK]` in the child table.  The child table contains a field `[SerialNum]` among other details (the child table has its own primary key `[ProductsID]` which is a sequential number.  I created a query named `[Customers Query]` to bring records from both tables together and I am producing an 1 page report for a ATF filing that requires the serial number.  Instead of creating a 1 page report (named `"Form3"`) for each record in the query as it does now, the client wants to have a range shown like "010001 - 010010" in that field.  My research has led me to MIN and MAX as well s FIRST and LAST parameters, but a) I don't think this is the best since some folks say those do NOT necessary return first and last records of the range, and b) I am completely stumped on how to write this expression in Access.

Im assuming that the logic would be something like this rudimentary (non programer) statement:

*If the count of records equals 1, then return `SerialNum`, otherwise return the the `SerialNum` from the first record and last record based on the Smallest and Greatest numbered value in the `ProductsID` field.*

I'm using Access 2013, and furthermore, I use the following macro to further filter the query to only my current record from a button on the form to display just those records in the report:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Form 3", acViewPreview, , "OrderID = " & OrderId
```

Comment: How about doing a MIN & MAX, then have a column that has something like 'If(MyMin <> MyMax, MyMin & "-" & MyMax, MyMin)

Answer (score 1):

If you make the query a group by query you can add two columns as indicated in the following screenshot:

[image: Example query in the designer]

Or if you prefer here is the example SQL:

```
SELECT Min(Products.SerialNum) AS MinOfSerialNum, Max(Products.SerialNum) AS MaxOfSerialNum
FROM Products;
```

The Last and First options will return the last and first entered values which may not be what you want.

You can also use the domain aggregate functions as the control source of a text box on the report like the following:

```
= DMax("[SerialNum]", "[Products]", "[OrderIDFK] = 1")
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark3308,  This works but needs to filter on OrderID.  It returns the Max of the query, and I'm filtering per my original comment.  I'm playing with it to see if I can make it work but the expression builder doesn't like my version which is: `=DMax("[SerialNum]","[Customers Query]","[OrderID] = OrderID")`  Thanks again for your prompt help.

Comment: I forgot to say, the last one seems the easy to me so I used it... if that wasn't obvious by my comment.  Thanks again for the time/expertise Mark